# How to projection in $geoNear aggregate method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
db.places.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 2,
        query: { type: "public" },
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 5,
        spherical: true
     }
   }
])
```

I am Using aggregate method in mongodb.and this is working for me but I need projection on the document for only return some field to show. So how can I achieve projection in this method

Comment: Projection means i want to show particular fields in returning documents. this query provide me the whole document but i want to return particular fields

Comment: You must use $project stage after $geoNear stage: dp.places.aggregate([{$geoNear:{...}},{{$project:{...}}])

Comment: @hecnabae Thank you so so...................... much  its working for me. you can answer it so that it may helps other......

Answer (score 0):

Even OP's problem is solved in the comments I decided to add an detailed answer as it will help some one else.

As @hecnabae said you have to append $project stage to your query to retrieve data.

Here is an example:

```
db.getCollection("places").aggregate(
[
{
"$geoNear": {
    "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
    "distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    "maxDistance": 2,
    "query": { "type": "public" },
    "includeLocs": "dist.location",
    "num": 5,
    "spherical": true
  }
},
{
"$project" : {
    "Name" : 1.0,
    "Distance" : "$dist.calculated",
    "Location": "$dist.location"
    }
}
],
{
"allowDiskUse" : false
}
);
```

This will return you an list of data as follows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3207128cbfe302dcbb1234"), 
    "Name" : "Your Place Name", 
    "Distance" : 17.98627020911569, 
    "Location" : [
        58.1230154, 
        23.1232555
    ]
}
```